# Telegram Python Bot Inline Menu and Dictionary

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

[Click Here to see the flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge6W4.png) I need some help with my Telegram bot. I am trying to create a bot that will allow me to modify a selected set of dictionary values and display the dictionary key and values in a certain way at the end of it. As shown in the code, right now I am having trouble trying to figure out how to find out which button did the user clicked and reflect it in the respective value of that key. (For example, (KEY)Shop A - (VALUE)Low Crowd, Compliant...so on and so forth for other shops in this selected area). Note that I have only wrote the code for Area 1 currently as an example -> It must also be able to work for other selected area with their own set of pre-defined dictionary keys with empty values. Refer to the image for a better understanding

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=C0116
    
    import logging
    
    from telegram import Update, ForceReply, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler
    
    # Enable logging
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
    )
    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    
    ############################ Keyboards #########################################
    def main_area_selection_kb():
        keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Area 1", callback_data='main_1'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Area 2", callback_data='main_2'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Area 3", callback_data='main_3'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Area 4", callback_data='main_4'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Area 5", callback_data='main_5'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Area 6", callback_data='main_6'),
            ],
        ]
        return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    
    def crowd_level_selection_kb():
        keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Low", callback_data='clvl_1'),
                InlineKeyboardButton("Moderate", callback_data='clvl_2'),
                InlineKeyboardButton("High", callback_data='clvl_3'),
                InlineKeyboardButton("Closed", callback_data='clvl_4'),
            ]
        ]
    
        return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    
    def compliance_kb():
        keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Compliant", callback_data='com_1'),
                InlineKeyboardButton("Not Compliant", callback_data='com_2'),
            ]
        ]
        return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    
    ############################ Selection #########################################
    def compliance_selection(update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
        query = update.callback_query
        query.answer()
        if query.data == 'com_1':
            query.message.reply_text('Compliant')
        elif query.data == 'com_2':
            query.message.reply_text('Not Compliant')
    
    def crowd_level_selection(update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
        query = update.callback_query
        query.answer() # How do I "pass" the dictionary in/return the value of the user selection back into the respective dictionary's key value?)
        if query.data == 'clvl_1':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Low Crowd') 
        elif query.data == 'clvl_2':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Moderate Crowd')
        elif query.data == 'clvl_3':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose High Crowd')
        elif query.data == 'clvl_4':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Closed')
    
    def main_area_selection(update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
        query = update.callback_query
    
        query.answer()
        # query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")
        if query.data == 'main_1':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Area 1')
            areamain(query)
        elif query.data == 'main_2':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Area 2')
        elif query.data == 'main_3':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Area 3')
        elif query.data == 'main_4':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Area 4')
        elif query.data == 'main_5':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Area 5')
        elif query.data == 'main_6':
            query.message.reply_text('You choose Area 6')
        else:
            query.message.reply_text('Error')
    
    ############################ Functions #########################################
    
    def start(update, context):
        """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
        update.message.reply_text('Please Choose an Area', reply_markup=main_area_selection_kb())
    
    
    def areamain(update):
        areamaindict = {'Shop A': '', 'Shop B': '', 'Shop C': '', 'Shop D': '', 'Shop E': ''}
    
        for i in areamaindict:
            update.message.reply_text(f"{i} Crowd Level:", 
reply_markup=crowd_level_selection_kb())
            

            #Next step: Add in menu for compliance
            #Following that, Set this i value to <High/Medium/Low> Crowd and <Compliant/Not Compliant> once user selected both respective buttons
    
    ############################ Main #########################################
    def main():
        
        # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
        updater = Updater("TOKEN")
    
        # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
        dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    
        # on different commands - answer in Telegram
        dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    
        ############################# Handlers #########################################
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_area_selection, pattern='main'))
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(crowd_level_selection, pattern='clvl'))
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(compliance_selection, pattern='com'))
    
    
        # Start the Bot/Listen for user input/messages
        updater.start_polling()
    
        # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
        # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
        # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
        updater.idle()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: In the callback handler split the callback.data like this \_, number = callback.data.split("\_")
then a basic if else will help you, like if number = 4: do something....

Comment: Hi @AlenPaulVarghese thanks for the suggestion! I would like to seek for some further clarification. Can you show me a simple example of the implementation? Because I can't seem to see how it would enable me to determine what button the user clicked and reflect it in the respective dictionary key's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that complaints is not implemented, hope that you can do it with the same design idea.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=C0116

import logging
from typing import Dict

from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    CallbackContext,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
)

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

temporary_data: Dict[int, dict] = {}


def compliance_kb():
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Compliant", callback_data="com_1"),
                InlineKeyboardButton("Not Compliant", callback_data="com_2"),
            ]
        ]
    )


# ########################### Selection #########################################
def compliance_selection(update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    if query.data == "com_1":
        query.message.reply_text("Compliant")
    elif query.data == "com_2":
        query.message.reply_text("Not Compliant")


def crowd_level_selection(update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    global temporary_data
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    main_area_number = query.data.split("_")[-1]

    # we need to identify the shop right? for that we can take the message for example Shop C Crowd Level:
    # so taking the first 6 charachter from the message we got the key

    shop_level = update.effective_message.text[:6]
    update.effective_message.delete()
    if "clvl_1" in query.data:
        query.message.reply_text(
            f"You choose Low Crowd of main area {main_area_number}"
        )
        temporary_data[query.from_user.id]["shop_data"][shop_level][
            "crowd_level"
        ] = "Low"
    elif "clvl_2" in query.data:
        query.message.reply_text(
            f"You choose Moderate Crowd of main area {main_area_number}"
        )
        temporary_data[query.from_user.id]["shop_data"][shop_level][
            "crowd_level"
        ] = "Moderate"
    elif "clvl_3" in query.data:
        query.message.reply_text(
            f"You choose High Crowd of main area {main_area_number}"
        )
        temporary_data[query.from_user.id]["shop_data"][shop_level][
            "crowd_level"
        ] = "High"
    elif "clvl_4" in query.data:
        query.message.reply_text(f"You choose Closed of main area {main_area_number}")
        temporary_data[query.from_user.id]["shop_data"][shop_level][
            "crowd_level"
        ] = "Closed"

    from pprint import pprint

    print(shop_level)
    pprint(temporary_data)


def main_area_selection(update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    global temporary_data
    temporary_data[update.effective_chat.id] = {}

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    each_shop_dict = {
        "Shop A": {"crowd_level": "null", "compliant": "null"},
        "Shop B": {"crowd_level": "null", "compliant": "null"},
        "Shop C": {"crowd_level": "null", "compliant": "null"},
        "Shop D": {"crowd_level": "null", "compliant": "null"},
        "Shop E": {"crowd_level": "null", "compliant": "null"},
    }  # or {f"Shop {k}":{"crowd_level": "null", "compliant": "null"} for k in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]} but this makes confusion.

    update.effective_message.delete()
    if "main" in query.data:
        number = query.data.split("_")[-1]
        query.message.reply_text(f"You choose Area {number}")
        temporary_data[query.from_user.id].update(
            dict(main_area_number=int(number), shop_data=each_shop_dict)
        )
    for i in each_shop_dict:
        main_area_number = query.data.split("_")[-1]
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
            [
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                        "Low", callback_data=f"clvl_1_{main_area_number}"
                    ),
                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                        "Moderate", callback_data=f"clvl_2_{main_area_number}"
                    ),
                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                        "High", callback_data=f"clvl_3_{main_area_number}"
                    ),
                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                        "Closed", callback_data=f"clvl_4_{main_area_number}"
                    ),
                ]
            ]
        )
        query.message.reply_text(f"{i} Crowd Level:", reply_markup=markup)


# ########################### Functions #########################################


def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    print(temporary_data.get(update.effective_chat.id, None))
    update.message.reply_text(
        "Please Choose an Area",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
            [
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Area 1", callback_data="main_1"),
                ],
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Area 2", callback_data="main_2"),
                ],
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Area 3", callback_data="main_3"),
                ],
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Area 4", callback_data="main_4"),
                ],
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Area 5", callback_data="main_5"),
                ],
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Area 6", callback_data="main_6"),
                ],
            ]
        ),
    )


# ########################### Main #########################################
def main():

    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # ############################ Handlers #########################################
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
        CallbackQueryHandler(main_area_selection, pattern="main")
    )
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
        CallbackQueryHandler(crowd_level_selection, pattern="clvl")
    )
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
        CallbackQueryHandler(compliance_selection, pattern="com")
    )

    # Start the Bot/Listen for user input/messages
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi once again @Alen Paul Varghese Thank you for taking time to answer my query, I've tried the code you've provided but I don't think it is what I am actually looking for but no worries as I've created a flowchart to show you my intended bot logic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge6W4.png Right now, I am stuck as to how can I link my predefined dictionary that was selected by the user to the inline button selections. (In short, how can I pass in the input from the inline button selection into the respective dictionary key's value)

Comment: @Firwer I edited some changes check again